# How to restrict unauthorized member to access the URL and redirect to some admin login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have couple of login pages: `laptopsearch.jsp`, `productsearch.jsp` and `gmailsearch.jsp`. The same logic is applied in every page.

If anyone tries to access this page then they are redirected to the admin login - `adminlogin.jsp`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let paramsString = (new URL(document.location).searchParams);
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);
  var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarKey");

  if (!searchParams.has("rwUrl") & someVarName == null) {
    var someVarName = "false";
    localStorage.setItem("someVarKey", someVarName);
    window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/adminlogin.jsp");
    location();
  else {
      if (icount == 0 & searchParams.has("tester")) {
        incrementCount();
        window.location.replace("http://localhost:8080/login? rwUrl=variable");
        location();
      }
    }
  });
```

1. On accessing any `xxxsearch.jsp` page it is redirecting to `adminlogin.jsp` while login in `adminlogin.jsp` and click on hyperlink redirect to `xxxsearch.jsp` page but when click on search button on `xxxxsearch.jsp` page it redirects to `adminlogin.jsp` dashboard.
2. Once we logout from `adminlogin.jsp`, if we try to access `xxxsearch.jsp` page it is accessible to everyone not redirecting to `adminlogin.jsp` page.

Expectation:

1. On click on search button should not redirect to `adminlogin.jsp` dashboard once we login.
2. Once we logout from `adminlogin.jsp` page in that case other `xxxsearch.jsp` page should not be accessible it should redirect to `adminlogin.jsp` page.

Kindly help on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A side note about your approach, authorisation/authentication should be done server side. Doing it client side makes it trivial to workaround, to the point where it's completely useless.

Comment: Also, you're missing a `}` to close the `if` condition block.

Comment: and `&&` instead of `&` in the conditions

Comment: Just to add to what @RoryMcCrossan pointed out, client side security isn't security at all. The server always must determine what is allowed, the client's concern with authorization is to provide a proper user experience, nothing more.

Comment: It really needs repeating - don't do this.